# OOP Issue in PHP with classes

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two classes, one is a database class that reads an ini file and creates a mysqli object and the other is a basic getter and setter via the database that has been loaded from the database class.

Am I missing something here?

The Options Class:

```
<?php
class Options {

    var $table;
    var $table_definitions;
    var $opt_db;

function __construct()
{
$this->opt_db = new mysqli("localhost","db_usr","db_pass","db"); # works
$this->opt_db = new DBConfig("db.ini"); # doesn't work
$this->table = "options";
$this->table_definitions = "options_definitions";
}
?>
```

The DBConfig Class:

```
<?php
Class DBConfig extends mysqli {


    var $host; 
    var $database; 
    var $user; 
    var $pass;
    var $db; 


function __construct($fn)
{

$file = @parse_ini_file($fn);
        $this->host = $file[host]; 
$this->host = "p:".$this->host;
        $this->database = $file[dbname]; 
        $this->user = $file[uname]; 
        $this->pass = $file[pwd]; 

//$this->db = 
return $this->db =  new mysqli($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->database) or die(mysqli_error());

}
?>
```

What needs to be done in order for the class to just work rather than doing a one liner of code. Effectively I don't want to be doing this for every class I make?

Thanks

Comment: Why extend `mysqli`? What does your `DBConfig` class do that `mysqli` does not?

Comment: It reads an ini file rather than having credentials being coded everywhere.

Comment: That's violating [SOLID principals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). What does reading in a configuration file have to do with connecting to MySQL database?

Comment: OK. I am completely unaware of SOLID, so I will be giving that a read... it has a lot to do with it in my opinion. Surely it's better to read from a config file than have all your credentials everywhere. Maybe I'm missing the point, so if I am , please enlighten me.

Comment: Oh, I completely agree that keeping configuration details in a separate file is great. In my mind, you'd be better off with a builder or factory class that reads from configuration and creates a database connection for you. The *single responsibility* of the database connection should be dealing with the database, not reading from config files.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are overriding the constructor function of the mysqli class you need to call it manually like so:

```
<?php
Class DBConfig extends mysqli {


    var $host; 
    var $database; 
    var $user; 
    var $pass;
    var $db; 


function __construct($fn)
{

  $file = @parse_ini_file($fn);
  $this->host = $file[host]; 
  $this->host = "p:".$this->host;
  $this->database = $file[dbname]; 
  $this->user = $file[uname]; 
  $this->pass = $file[pwd]; 

  return parent::__construct( $this->host , $this->user , $this->pass , $this->database );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you must add quotation marks or apostrophes.

Just replace this:

```
    $this->host = $file[host]; 
    $this->host = "p:".$this->host;
    $this->database = $file[dbname]; 
    $this->user = $file[uname]; 
    $this->pass = $file[pwd];
```

with this:

```
    $this->host = $file["host"]; 
    $this->host = "p:".$this->host;
    $this->database = $file["dbname"]; 
    $this->user = $file["uname"]; 
    $this->pass = $file["pwd"];
```

And btw... `__construct()` does not return a value, but an instance of the class

change this:

```
return $this->db = $this->db =  new mysqli($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->database) or die(mysqli_error());
```

with this:

```
parent::__construct( $this->host , $this->user , $this->pass , $this->database );
```